# contrasts error in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Hi i am passing arguments in R.when i passing the string value i am getting the following error.

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'addresstest.txt'
```

this is my code

```
input <- function(CITY,ADDRESS)     
{
delhi <- read.delim("addresstest.txt", na.strings = "")
delhi$lnprice <- log(delhi$PRIMARY_PRICE) # creating log price variable
uidel = lm (lnprice ~ CITY+AREA_SQFT+BEDS+BATHS+ADDRESS,data = delhi) 
model <- predict (uidel,data.frame(CITY=CITY,ADDRESS=ADDRESS), na.rm = TRUE)
model
}
```

passing the values by

```
input(CITY=NCR,ADDRESS=Sector78)
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error message seems to be telling you that one of your variables has only one level ... you can check this with `table` or `nlevels`. (compare to the output of `lm(1 ~ factor(1))`)

Comment: can u explain deeply.i am new to r language

Comment: PS.. id try doing this correctly outside a function first

Comment: When you read in your data, some variables (the categorical) will be converted to factors. If they have only one unique level then coefficients cannot be estimated. So check the number of unique values for each of your predictors.

Comment: Might be worth having a read of the r intro https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html